# Static typing not working when printing the "type()" function

Tags: python, types

This issue came across when I was trying to statically type Python like this:

```
maybeFloat: float = 2
```

But when I'm trying to print the type of the variable doing this:

```
print(type(maybeFloat))
```

The console logs this:

```
<class 'int'>
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the purpose of static typing in Python if it is not going to work?

Comment: There is no static typing in python, these are called annotations. They are supposed to provide readability, replace typing comments and also to make linters do a great job. They are solely a suggestion, Python typing is still dynamic.

Comment: I didn't know that. I was hoping that finally one of the worst problems of Python has been finally resolved but that does not seems the case. Anyway, thanks for the clarification! Have a nice day.

Comment: @Pedro Please don't post answers in the comments. Post it as an answer, and I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is no such thing as static typing in python.
`var : int = 1` is an annotation. Something only useful as documentation.

Even you can assign any type to a typed variable :

```
x float = 'I am a float!'
```

Also the the 'types' does not need to be types:

`x: 'hello'`  # x is a 'hello'

Annotations reside in the `__annotations__` variable.
So you can use it as a namespace to hold variables

```
x: 3.14
print(__annotations__[x]) # -> 3.14
```

Thats not very useful though